# Update a payment_status from "Pending" to "Completed" with PayPal IPN. Does it resend the txn_id?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

On the PayPal site in their PHP code for dealing with the IPN they do some minor checks and then put in some comments as to what to do next.

One of the comments is

```
// check that txn_id has not been previously processed
```

Indicating that if it has been processed there is something wrong.

What happens when a payment_status goes from "Pending" to "Completed", it would surely send the same txn_id wouldn't it? How else would you identify the transaction and update the record in the database and what "txn_type" is posted for that specific IPN message?

The IPN has been around for years but still the documentation can be so vague and badly explained in most places. They leave you guessing as to what happens in lots of scenarios instead of explaining in detail.

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction ID should be the unique id of the transaction that occurred, the logic that you noted is to make sure that the transaction is not duplicated (eg. not inserted more than once in the system), transaction updates should have the same transaction id. So you should check if the transaction id exists, if so update according fields if you see fit.

Comment: And would the "txn_type" be "subscr_payment" when it is updating from "Pending" to "Completed"?

Comment: @David the txn_type will not change, payment_status and pending_reason  will change as far as I can remember. Other stuff like the total and stuff will change if refunded. Best way to check is to check the IPN logs in paypal to see what kind of data is being sent.